# Estimated normal density is fat-tailed?

Tags: normal-distribution, estimation, density-function

I wanted to check what is the relative error of an estimated N(0, 1) density function. By relative error I mean:

$$\alpha(x) = E \bigg ( \frac{f(x|\hat{\mu}, \hat{\sigma})}{f(x|0,1)} \bigg ) - 1$$

where $f(\cdot, \mu, \sigma)$ is the normal pdf.

To get an estimate of $\alpha(x)$ I simulated $10^3$ data points from a N(0, 1), estimated sample mean and variance and evaluate the relative error at 100 points $x \in (-6, 6)$. I repeated these steps $reps$ times to calculate the average relative error.

This is the R code:

```
nX = 100
reps <- 1000
X <- seq(-6, 6, length.out = nX)
myM <- matrix(NA, reps, nX)

for(ii in 1:reps)
{
 data <- rnorm(1000)
 myM[ii, ] <- dnorm(X, mean = mean(data), sd = sd(data))/dnorm(X) - 1
}

plot(X, colMeans(myM), type = 'l', ylab = expression(hat(alpha)),
     xlab = "x")
```

I expected the relative error to be close to 0 for every $x$, but to my surprise it looks like the estimated normal has fatter tails that the real thing.

So my questions are:

1) Is this tail behaviour happening because of Jensen inequality (since $f()$
   is non-linear)?

2) Suppose I want to use another density estimator, and I want to check how 
   well it does in terms of relative error. I thought that for a normal I could just calculate mean and variance and use the resulting density as a "gold standard" against which I could compare other density estimators. Is there a sensible way to compare how well different density estimators are doing for different values of $x$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some thinking and experimentation my conclusions are the following:

1) The "fat-tails" are consequence of Jensen Inequality, given that the 
   second derivative of the Gaussian density is positive in the tails:

$$\frac{\partial^2 \phi(x)}{\partial x^2} = (-1 + x^2)e^{-0.5x^2} > 0$$

for $|x| > 1$.

2) The relative error I was using is not ideal because the ratio of
   densities is quite unstable. Using the Kullback-Leibler
   divergence makes much more sense to compare densities.